# Jasper Reports: what is the bestway to join two datasets together from different data adapters?

Tags: jasper-reports

There are two datasets in the report, one query from oracle JDBC adaper and another query from mysql JDBC Adapter.
The two datasets can join by specific field. How can i join them into one dataset, or filter a dataset by values from another dataset?

for example:

1. Data files in Finance System:
   [ orderId, paid, total ]
2. Data fields in CRM System:
   [ orderId, customer, saler ]

I want to combine the two dataset into one by orderId, result as:
[ orderId, customer, saler, paid, total ]

Comment: Are you using JasperServer or custom application to generate reports?

Comment: I'm using JasperServer Community 7.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JasperServer you can do it using Virtual Data Source which will combine two JDBC Data Sources for you. You can find step by step tutorial here: https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-administrator-guide/v71/virtual-data-sources

When you have Virtual Data Source configured you should create Domain where you can join tables from that Virtual Data Source as you want. You can find step by step tutorial how to do that here: https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-user-guide/example-creating-domain-using-virtual-data-source

Comment: Thank you very much @cgrim. But i can not create domain in Jasperreports Server 7.x Community Edition, it's a commercial feature of data virtualization(https://www.jaspersoft.com/editions) at least professional edition.

Comment: Then there can be another option - write own data source in Java. You can create own Java bean class for storing values - `Order` for example. That custom data source will select separately values from Oracle into `Map` where `orderId` values will be as a key and `Order` instance as a value. Then it will select all values from MySQL and complete values in the map using `orderId` as a lookup. Result collection of `Order` instances will be then used in the report.

Comment: Hi @cgrim, that's really a feasible solution. But now, i'm trying to build my own teiid server to provide a VDB. As mentioned in document, jasper report provides it's data virtualization feature by teiid engine too.